# Connecting just a piece of number array in matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, graph, 3d

Given a 3D scatter plot with 7 points.  These 7 points, geometrically make a double tetrahedron.  I am able to connect all of the bottom points(z=0) to the apex(z=4/3 * sqrt(3)).

The base is made two triangles that have a common centroid(middle point), which is directly under the apex.

How do I outline the two triangles that make up the base?

In my number arrays, the points for the base would be [index0,1,2] for the first triangle and [index3,4,5] for the second and the [index7] would be the apex of the double pyramid(tetrahedron).

The image below shows what I would like to see.  The missing lines are in red.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

tr = m.sqrt(3.)
sx = m.sqrt(6.)

x = np.array([4.,2.,6.,4.,6.,2.,4.])
y = np.array([1.,1.+2*tr,1.+2*tr,1+(8*tr)/3,1+(2*tr)/3,1+(2*tr)/3,1+(4*tr)/3])
z = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,(4*sx)/3])


ax.scatter(x,y,zs = z, s=100)

for r, s, t in zip(x, y, z):
    X = np.array([r, 4.])
    Y = np.array( [s, 1+(4*tr)/3])
    Z = np.array([t, (4*sx)/3])
    ax.plot3D(X, Y, Z, 'b')


ax.set_ylim([0,8])
ax.set_xlim([8,0])
ax.set_zlim([0,8])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great picture, interesting code, but... What is the question?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks.  The question is:  How can I draw the two red triangles in the image in Python code, hopefully using my x,y,z data set.  I'm thinking it'll involve striding the lists [0:3][4:6]>> to [7].  I'm fairly new to Python/and very new to numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some Code:

To plot the missing vertices:

```
for index in range(6):
    import math
    next_idx = (index+1) % 3 + math.floor(index / 3) * 3
    X = (x[index], x[next_idx])
    Y = (y[index], y[next_idx])
    Z = (z[index], z[next_idx])
    ax.plot3D(X, Y, Z, 'r')
```

### A Small Explanation:

The operative code is:

```
    next_idx = (index+1) % 3 + math.floor(index / 3) * 3
```

this uses the fact that the data comes in triads.  It selects the `next index` based on the `current index plus one` but staying in a group of 3.  This effectively chooses all three elements of the triangles, in all possible sequences.

This works because `(index+1) % 3` will only take the values `0, 1, 2`, while `math.floor(index / 3) * 3` takes the values `0, 3, 6...`.  So it ends up being:

```
index, next_idx
  0      1
  1      2
  2      0
  3      4
  4      5
  5      3
```

### Alternate Ending:

This can also be done without the loop, using a [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php):

```
X = [x[i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 0)]
Y = [y[i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 0)]
Z = [z[i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 0)]
ax.plot3D(X, Y, Z, 'r')

X = [x[i] for i in (3, 4, 5, 3)]
Y = [y[i] for i in (3, 4, 5, 3)]
Z = [z[i] for i in (3, 4, 5, 3)]
ax.plot3D(X, Y, Z, 'r')
```

### Picture:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Great answer!  Could you explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: Amazing.  I'm wondering how you got it so the 3rd point isn't connecting to the 4th point.  Trying hard to pick it apart here.